# Cocoa's widget - TextField for key shortcuts editing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, widget, components

Is there such thing? I want to extend and reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shortcut Recorder](http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/)

If you want to use the Interface Builder plugin you'll have to create your project in Xcode 3, then migrate it to Xcode 4.